# Magento 2.3 removed Webservicex and Yahoo Finance Exchange

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, currency

What i see in magento 2.2 and 2.3 is that Webservicex and Yahoo Finance Exchange are removed.

Why are they removed?
What are the alternative to them?
How can i add them back?

Comment: Any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Yahoo and webservicex has deprecated their Currency Converter Api Service. In Magento 2.2 you will find an service not found error. Try this module https://github.com/thanhdv2811/Magento-2-Currency-Convert

Comment: I used the above plugin but some of the currency e.g KWD shows "We can't retrieve a rate from https://frankfurter.app/current?from=USD&to=KWD."